# c++ libcurl json rest

Tags: c++, json, curl, libcurl

I am trying to download a json file from a REST webpage in C++ with libcurl.
The following code works if I go to the webpage but it doesnt download if I try to access the json ....

I think it should be an easy fix but I cant find any reference to this ...

If I go to webpage it opens the json but this code only returns  text/html; charset=utf-8

??????????

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; // init to NULL is important 
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");   

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://web.com/api/json/123");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://web.com/123.html");//this works!!!
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(CURLE_OK == res) {
        char *ct;
        /* ask for the content-type */
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
        if((CURLE_OK == res) && ct)
            printf("We received Content-Type: %s\n", ct);
    }
}
/* always cleanup */ 
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
std::string ServerContent::DownloadJSON(std::string URL)
{   
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; // init to NULL is important 
    std::ostringstream oss;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");  
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8"); 
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) 
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,writer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (CURLE_OK == res) 
        { 
            char *ct;         
            res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
            if((CURLE_OK == res) && ct)
                return *DownloadedResponse;
        }
    }

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
}


static std::string *DownloadedResponse;

static int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *buffer_in)
{

    // Is there anything in the buffer?  
    if (buffer_in != NULL)  
    {
        // Append the data to the buffer    
        buffer_in->append(data, size * nmemb);

        // How much did we write?   
        DownloadedResponse = buffer_in;

        return size * nmemb;  
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have two calls to `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);` I believe the second one is not needed.

Comment: Also from my experience it seems you should assign the return value of curl_slist_append back to headers in order to modify the list.

Comment: you are missing a call to `curl_slist_free(headers)` so this code leaks the header list

Comment: @PeteKirkham you are missing _all. curl_slist_free_all(headers);

Comment: Your `curl_slist_append` calls aren't appending anything: you're ignoring the return value.

Comment: must be a slow day at the convienent store lol

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the configuration on the HTTP server. First, you should be sending some type of indication of what type you're expecting, for example, adding an `Accept` header like this:

```
Accept: application/json
```

If you don't specify what you're expecting, the server may return the default HTML in the response header `Content-Type`, and that's what `curl` says to you.

Comment: I tried to add the following but I cant get to the actually data from the server response.... struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; // init to NULL is important 
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");  
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach from the tutorial code at the curl site?
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html

Comment: I want to read the json not put it, is there a CURLOPT_READHEADER or something to read the stream of data returned from server?  btw this worls for me on the command line curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET web.com/api/json/123