# How to use Web API's with C++ language?

Tags: c++, api, roblox

So i've been learning OOP is quite a while now and wanted to test out the little knowledge i have.. I wanted to use some API provided by the website, This API Checks if a username is already been taken. But how will i do it with C++? Where will i start?

This is :

> http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=bob1

The username is taken so:

```
{
    "success" :true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ from a box does not provide a support of HTTP protocol and a JSON parser. You should use third party libraries such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and [libjson](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5780603/1036311) is an example, how to use libcurl to download a JSON data.